# Dagger 2 and dependency injection hell?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

How do you use dagger from Kotlin?

I've been in a loop of fixing one compile error and moving to another and at the end I get back to step 1

Here is all I need:

- AppDependencies
- GenericActivityDependencies
- PerActivityDependency

Here are my main dependencies:

App

```
@Module
class ApplicationModule(private val application: Application) {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideContext(): Application = this.application
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules = [ HttpModule::class, ApplicationModule::class ])
interface AppComponent {
    val app: Application
}
```

Why do I need to once provide the dependency in the module and another time define it in the component?

Activity Module

```
@Module
class ActivityModule(private val activity: Activity) {

    @PerActivity
    @Provides
    @ActivityContext
    fun provideContext(): Context = activity
}

@Component(modules = [ActivityModule::class], dependencies = [AppComponent::class])
@ActivityContext
interface ActivityComponent {
    fun inject(activity: MainActivity)
}
```

HomeModule

```
@Module
class LandingModule {
    @PerActivity
    @Provides
    fun provideSomethig(): Something {
        return  Something()
    }
}
@SomeActivity
@Subcomponent(modules = [LandingModule::class])
interface LandingSubcomponent {
    val something: Something
}
```

By this point, I have written more code than there needs to be in my whole activity.

- I get errors like can't inherit from a scopes component
- Can't generate Dagger gencode
- Subcomponent needs a different scope

How do I achieve this?

Is there a better di for kotlin?

Is there a sample somewhere I could follow that has per activity module?

Comment: lol. I feel you brah. What version are you _trying_ to use? How are `@PerActivty`, `@ActivityContext`, and `@SomeActivity` defined?

Comment: This might be helpful https://proandroiddev.com/dagger-2-android-defeat-the-dahaka-b1c542233efc

Comment: I think it's pretty clear the OP can do, and has done, many Google searches and posting yet another article is not as helpful

Comment: Try not making your question look like a rant, it might end up being useful to future visitors then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand your frustrations. I have been there before and it took me quite some time to understand dagger myself. Just a quick demo/tutorial.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class])
interface AppComponent {
    fun context(): Context
}

@Module
class AppModule(private val application: Application) {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApplication(): Application= application
}
```

The component is the interface to the container. Anything defined in here can be accessible if you are able to instantiate your container successfully. Also, it is the interface to other containers/components. This means that if you want to expose something outside your container, you define it here. Therefore,

> Why the heck do I need to once provide the dependency in the module
>   and another time define it in the component. This is plain stupid.

is not always true. You don't need to define anything in your component if you don't want anything to expose outside. An alternative to exposing would be injecting.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class])
interface AppComponent {
    fun inject(activity: MainActivity)
}
```

You are not exposing anything here but you can still get the activity context from the container thru inject.

Now let's proceed to scoping.

Scoping is the way to provide 'local singletons' inside your container. A scoped dependency will be created only once inside the container. An example is your PerActivity scope. A scoped component will only accept a module that is scoped with the same Scope. For example:

```
@PerActivity
@Component(dependencies = [AppComponent::class],
        modules = [ActivityModule::class])
interface ActivityComponent{
    fun inject(activity: MainActivity)
}
```

The corresponding module should only be scoped with PerActivity as well.

```
class ActivityModule(activity:Activity) {
    @PerActivity
    @Provides
    fun provideActivity() = activity
}
```

Any other scope defined in your module that is not the same scope as your intended component will result in a compile error. Multiple scopes is not allowed as well.

As for the component dependencies, you can use use `dependencies` or `subcomponents`. If dependencies is used, any dependency that is required by the child must be exposed by the parent. In our case above, if the ActivityComponent requires the activity context, the AppComponent must define a function that returns it. In subcomponents, just define your subcomponent in your component and the dependencies will be resolved internally.

I have written a small guide to learning dagger 2. If you are interested, you can go check it out.
https://medium.com/tompee/android-dependency-injection-using-dagger-2-530aa21961b4
https://medium.com/tompee/dagger-2-scopes-and-subcomponents-d54d58511781

Comment: This is great, my biggest misunderstanding was that the activityModule and Activity component were for generic activity. But that's actually per activity per my current understanding.

Comment: Your article is the best one explaining Dagger I've run into some far. Cheers!

Comment: I don't think the following question deserve a new one, or there's probably a dupe hidden around here, but I still don't see a difference between exposing and injecting since for me both imply that the object already has the dependency, what's the deal there?

Comment: Nothing much really outside component dependency. Just a matter of convenience and preference. Exposing allows you to request for an instance in a straightforward manner. Injecting is pretty limited as it has to do either field or method injection.

Answer (score 1):

> Why the heck do I need to once provide the dependency in the module and another time define it in the component. This is plain stupid.

I agree, but don't be discouraged by that fact, because once you learn to master it you'll learn to appreciate it and really take advantage. I've been using version 2.2 for a while without any issues. I've only needed to define one annotation, add a pair of additional dependencies (AutoDagger among them, which takes care of that *component feature*), and use the following structure:

```
/*   Dagger   */
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.2"
// Fix: github.com/rharter/auto-value-gson/issues/43#issuecomment-219994018
kapt 'com.squareup:javapoet:1.9.0'
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.2"
compileOnly 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'

/*  Autodagger   */
kapt "com.github.lukaspili.autodagger2:autodagger2-compiler:1.1"
implementation "com.github.lukaspili.autodagger2:autodagger2:1.1"
```

**DaggerScope.java**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Scope
@interface DaggerScope {
}
```

**YourApp.kt**

```
@AutoComponent(modules = [YourApp.Module::class])
@AutoInjector
@DaggerScope
class YourApp : Application() {
    ...

    @Singleton @dagger.Module
    inner class Module(private val app : YourApp) {
        @Provides @AutoExpose(YourApp::class) fun application(): Application = app
        @Provides @AutoExpose(YourApp::class) fun context(): Context = app
        ...
        // Stuff like your database or base service can go here
    }
}
```

**SomeActivity.kt**

```
@AutoComponent(dependencies = [YourApp::class],
        modules = [SomeActivity.Module::class])  // you are free to add other modules here
@AutoInjector
@DaggerScope
class SomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    ...
    @dagger.Module
    inner class Module() {
         @Provides @AutoExpose(SomeActivity::class) fun something(): Something {
               return some way of creating Something
         }
         /*  specific deps for SomeAcitivity's actions, like specific services. 
             You can also access DAOs as you've got access to the DB   */
    }
}
```

You can also mimic this structure with a `Fragment` instead of an `Activity`.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: This looks much cleaner, question why does your activity has dependency on the application class?

Comment: it's not an activity dependency. `AutoComponent` needs to know if you wish to use another component, which practically turns the activity component into a subcomponent without boilerplate. It might me correct to use `YourApp.Module` instead, as it might be a "typo" on my side. **EDIT** I was incorrect. What `AutoComponent` needs is the children `Component`, and since it's autogenerated, you can't reference it yet

Comment: thanks, but the module deopendency is defined under `modules`, so what do i put under dependencies?

Comment: also when I run this it's complaingin `Provider butterknife.compiler.ButterKnifeProcessor could not be instantiated` do i have to use butterkniffe?

Comment: Your app. Are you worried about it being an actual runtime dependency? It won't happen.

Comment: No. It's not necessary to use ButterKnife. That's a weird error